# PHP DOM parser breaks the page and can't load page content

Tags: php, html, dom, php-parser

I have created a php parser that must extract the price in a span tag, but  when I echo the $html so that I could see how the page loads, it shows me a broken page with no contents. Instead only header and footer loads, but not the content. The content seems to load by JavaScript externally and my question is how can I load the html page with Dom so that JavaScript also loads? I need to let the whole content load so that I can get the divs and spans. This is my code:

```
<?php

require_once('simple_html_dom.php');

$url = 'http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/product.do?cid=99570&vid=1&pid=714649002';

$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'UTF-8');
$html = file_get_html($url);

echo $html;

if(is_object($html)){

    foreach ( $html->find('span#priceText') as $data){

        $raw_price = $data->innertext;

        echo $raw_price;


    }
 }
?>
```

Comment: Instead of doing it manually use : simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/ class

Comment: but in my code I have created a Dom object. Or maybe I didn't understand what you mean

Comment: @jewelhuq And what do you mean by instead of doing it manually?

Comment: You are parsing data and writing code line by line instead if you download & add class you can do it easily with one or two line of code.

Comment: @jewelhuq but I did add the Dom to my code. But that is not what my problem is. My problem is that the web page with a content doesn't want to load at all. Instead only header and footer loads, but never the content. The content is called by JavaScript externally and my question is how can I load the html page with Dom so that JavaScript also loads?

Answer (score 0):

**Alt aproach**

The link you are actually looking for (in his minimal expression) is this: http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/productData.do?pid=714649

Now load that using curl, put a value to the `unknownShopperId` cookie, explode it into an array and get the price you need:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/productData.do?pid=714649");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Cookie: unknownShopperId=E853DA3B2607DDAA5F2FE13CE8D32ACF"));

$result = curl_exec($ch);
$explode = explode(',', $result);

echo 'Original price: ' . $explode[92] . '<br/>' .
'New price: ' . $explode[93] . '<br/>' .
'Both prices: ' . $explode[13];
```

The result will be: `'$14.94'`

From now on, if you need another price you must know the intem's `pid`

Comment: Oh wow! Thank you! But where did you get the value for the cookie and does that mean that this value for the cookie might change in the future?

Comment: You can randomize that value AFAIK, if your request lacks of it, the site will try to set it for you, along with a 301 response which will result in a null answer for `curl`. A fixed value seems to work all the time, I changed it to random requests and it still works.

Comment: Thank you so much for this help! I have one more question and it might be silly. I am not so much into php, but the $explode[92], 92 is where the original price is located after counting comas, I want to know if there is a way of knowing where each data is located or you have to always try numbers like 1, 2, 92, 93 and so on before guessing it? Is there a technic for it?

Comment: I wanted to collect the links with pids using simillar method from http://oldnavy.gap.com/browse/category.do?cid=6072&mlink=6027,10148629,DP_Sec_G_5_GraphicTees&clink=10148629 but it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I was out for the weekend, it has to be the same numbers all the time: 92 for the original price, 93 for a new price in case of discounts and such and 13 for both prices separated by space.

Comment: About collecting pid's... product population is done with JS as well but I'm out of time to reverse engineer that. An **alt aproach** would be to search for nothing specific but a category ID: `http://oldnavy.gap.com/resources/productSearch/v1/search?cid=1013969`. This will give you lots of info about each product including prices and if I'm not wrong `parentBusinessCatalogItemId`will be the `PID`, you can use `json_decode()` to parse that data inot an array.